# What is this message when installing Pybrain

Tags: python, python-2.7, pybrain

I checked out the latest version of Pybrain from [github](https://github.com/pybrain/pybrain)

Running `sudo python setup.py install` on my mac gives me:

```
Extracting PyBrain-0.3.1-py2.7.egg to /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PyBrain-0.3.1-py2.7.egg/build/lib/build/lib/pybrain/optimization/distributionbased/fem.py", line 235
    updateSize = self._computeUpdateSize(self._computeDensities(sample), k)
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PyBrain-0.3.1-py2.7.egg/build/lib/pybrain/optimization/distributionbased/fem.py", line 235
    updateSize = self._computeUpdateSize(self._computeDensities(sample), k)
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PyBrain-0.3.1-py2.7.egg/pybrain/optimization/distributionbased/fem.py", line 235
    updateSize = self._computeUpdateSize(self._computeDensities(sample), k)
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What is this; should I worry about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in line `233`, which is:

```
print(len(self.allsamples), min(self.fitnesses), max(self.fitnesses)#, self.alphas)
```

it comments out the `self.alphas` part, but it is also commenting out the closing parenthesis of the `print` function, so the error occurs.

I'll submit a pull request, meanwhile, you can fix it yourself by fixing the parenthesis.

Comment: Is this the right path in the repo: `./pybrain/optimization/distributionbased/fem.py`?

Comment: Yes, if `.` is your module's root.

Comment: Actually, why are there three paths? Are they not all the same?

Comment: They're the same file, but it's kinda continuing the process and encounters the same error over and over.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'll try to fix these on the repo as I see it. I didn't realise this library would be in such a bad state.

Comment: I fixed the error, ran `python setup.py bdist_egg` and installed it again, but the error persists; what am I doing wrong?

Comment: nvm, i needed to delete the build & dist dirs

Answer (score 0):

It is a syntax **error** so you should at least raise a ticket on it and possibly resolve it and submit a patch. It looks like fem at least will not work but the error may be on line 234 as there is nothing obviously wrong with the reported line.